# How to choose which Storyboard loads

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I need to choose which `MainViewController.h` to load depending on the iPhone model that the app is running on. Using the code below, I distinguish between iPhone 4/4S and 5/5S/5C. Because of the auto layout, I will need to create two `mainViewController.h`s and then choose depending on the model of the phone. How do I do this? This is the code I have:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5         ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {

        NSLog(@"Iphone 5");


    } else {

        NSLog(@"Iphone4");

    }
}
```

So please tell me how to chose `MainViewController.h`.

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (screenSize.height == 568) {
        // iPhone 5
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        // iPhone 4
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
    }

    UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming from the tag that you're using storyboards? And if so, are the two MainViewControllers part of two separate storyboards?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Yes. There are two storyboards and i need to choose which one will load....

Comment: @LyndseyScott Thanks for the correction. I wrote this post quickly before leaving... So there were many mistakes... So I'm sorry and thanks for correcting!

Comment: @LyndseyScott When I moved the code up it worked. THANKS AND HAPPY EASTER!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify which storyboard to load, do so in your `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Load the storyboard that corresponds to the screen size using its storyboard name, ex:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;

CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (screenSize.height == 568) {
    // iPhone 5, i.e. 568 pixels high
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone5" bundle:nil];  
} else {
    // earlier model iPhones, i.e. 480 pixels high
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone4" bundle:nil];      
}

UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: ok.... I encountered a small problem... The app still loads the old STORYBOARD FOR THE IPHONE 5....

Comment: Could you post your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method?

Comment: Oh god... I'm so sorry... I moved the code up and it wroked perfectly! Thanks a lot and now Finally, and really: THANK YOU VERY MUCH AND HAPPY EASTER!